# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device when using Azure Shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

When running **any** az based command in Azure Cloud Shell I receive a tonne of errors related to Python with the only tangible one being here:

e.g just the command `az` by itself.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 996, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 976, in flush
    self.stream.flush()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is an edge case caused by myself moving around large files.
 
You can find your mounted drive by looking at the resource group:
 "cloud-shell-storage-[region name]"-> A storage account with a random-looking name-> File Shares -> then find a file share with your name in it.

There may be multiple resource groups in different regions, keep looking until you find a file share with your name in the title.

[image: screen shot of azure file share]

You could increase the quota or delete some files.

Alternatively, go nuclear and delete the file share (not the account as other people may be using it!!), then in the azure shell do `cloudrive unmount` however you will lose everything including your command history. So you may prefer to increase the quota / delete files instead.