# Unable to connect to AKS Cluster from Azure Cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cloud-shell

Trying to connect AKS cluster from azure cloud shell and getting the below issue.
[image]

Also getting the same error while running other commands as well.

Could anyone suggest/guide resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in my environment, and it is working fine for me.

[image]

The error you are facing is generally comes when your cloud shell storage->FileShare is full. You can check the FileShare Properties which you have created while connecting with AzureCloudShell.

[image]

You could increase the quota or delete some files to resolve the issue.

You can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835944/oserror-errno-28-no-space-left-on-device-when-using-azure-shell) in which another user encountered the same kind of error.